# getting a lot of TransactionManagementError in production servers

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, django-sessions

Lately getting a lot of errors likes this:

```
An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "
TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

the exceptions are not in context of tests (like in other stack overflow questions). these exception comes from many different views and apis together at some point of the day.

I'm running Django 1.7.1, Python 2.7, MySql 5.7 (Google Cloud Managed)

Could it be related to Django DB Sessions?

I see this code in  SessionStore.save()   (\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py)

```
       with transaction.atomic(using=using):
            obj.save(force_insert=must_create, using=using)
```

Could a Session save cause other requests to return TransactionManagementError

this is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
   response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 57, in wrapped_view
   return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/opt/webapps/app/reports/api.py", line 573, in track_album_played
   albumStore = AlbumStore.objects.only('id').get(id=album_store_id)
 File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 351, in get
   num = len(clone)
 File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 122, in __len__
   self._fetch_all()
 File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 966, in _fetch_all
   self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
 File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator
   for row in compiler.results_iter():
 File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 700, in results_iter
   for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
 File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
   cursor.execute(sql, params)
 File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 59, in execute
   self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
 File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 386, in validate_no_broken_transaction
   "An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "
TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

reports/api.py:560

```
@csrf_exempt 
def track_album_played(request):
    album_store_id= request.REQUEST.get('album_store_id')
    album_origin_id= request.REQUEST.get('album_origin_id')

    bundle_id= request.GET.get('bundle_id')
    albumStore = None

    if(album_store_id):
        album_store_id=album_store_id.replace('?','')
        try:
            albumStore = AlbumStore.objects.only('id').get(id=album_store_id)
```

Comment: show this file api.py line 550

Comment: added the beginning of the function